Is it possible to add .svg image over live camera view? (Swift)
So i’m new to Swift but I’ve been searching for days now and there seem to be no explanation or tutorial on how to overlay a vector image over live camera view, whether it be AVfoundation or UIImagePicker. Closest thing i came across is custom overlay with UIBezier thingy you write equations to draw curves overlaying live cam view. Is it possible to do such thing? All I want is just to overlay ruler, protractor, fibonacci curve, etc over live camera view. Here i include some images to depict my goal. The aim is to help urban sketchers measure the visual/ and improve their perspective sketching skill.
Below is my code. The problem is 'camView.layer.addSublayer(ViewFinder)' where the ViewFinder variable can only be CALayer and not vector image.
image: goal of the program
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    

    @IBOutlet var camView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ViewFinder: UIImage!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //imageView.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        
        button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        button.setTitle("Cam On",
                        for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white,
                             for: .normal)
        
    }
            
    @IBAction func didTapButton() {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.cameraOverlayView = self.addOverlay()
        present(picker, animated: true)
    }
    
    func addOverlay() -> UIView? {
        self.addViewFinder(camView)
        camView.frame = self.view.frame
        camView.tag = 101
        return camView
    }
    func addViewFinder(_ camView: UIView){
        camView.layer.addSublayer(ViewFinder)
    }

}

extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate  {
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        guard let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
            return
        }
        camView.image = image
    }
}

